# In VBA : Dim a, b as String ==> only b is a String. Can I get a reference to this behavior?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In a VBA module in Access 2013 I've been bitten by this:

```
Dim a, b as String
```

a is a Variant, b is a String

Where can I get a reference to this behavior?

On the MSDN page ["Dim Statement (Visual Basic)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx) I see the following example:

> ```
>    Dim a, b, c As Single, x, y As Double, i As Integer  
>    ' a, b, and c are all Single; x and y are both Double
> ```

which is not the same behavior.

Comment: There's information part-way down this Chip Pearson page: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong documentation. VB is not VBA.

From the [VBA documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx):

> You can declare several variables in one statement. To specify a data type, you must include the data type for each variable. In the following statement, the variables `intX` , `intY` and `intZ` are declared as type **Integer**.
>
> ```
> Dim intX As Integer, intY As Integer, intZ As Integer
> ```
>
> In the following statement, `intX` and `intY` are declared as type **Variant** only and `intY` are declared as type **Variant** only `intZ` is declared as type **Integer**.
>
> ```
> Dim intX, intY, intZ As Integer
> ```
>
> You don't have to supply the variable's data type in the declaration statement. If you omit the data type, the variable will be of type **Variant**.